# Questions about the logic and scope of a destructor that frees a linked list from memory

Tags: c++

I have a class called `Stopwatch` that I'm working on (so please ignore most of the incompleteness below). Its interface is supposed to be a good abstraction of what a stopwatch is like in real life. Right now I'm trying to write the destructor, which will free the memory for the linked list that represents all the laps.

```
class Stopwatch
{
    typedef enum {UNSTARTED, RUNNING, PAUSED, FINISHED} state;
    typedef struct
    {
        unsigned hours;
        unsigned minutes;
        unsigned seconds;
    } time;
    typedef struct
    {
       unsigned n; // lap number
       time t; // lap time
       lap* next_ptr;
    } lap;

    public: 
    Stopwatch();
    ~Stopwatch();
    void right_button(); // corresponds to start/stop/pause
    void left_button();  // corresponds to lap/reset

    private: 
    state cur_state;
    lap* first_ptr;

}

Stopwatch::Stopwatch()
{
    cur_state = UNSTARTED;
    first_ptr = NULL;
}

Stopwatch::~Stopwatch()
{
    // Destroy all laps
    for (lap* thisptr = first_ptr; thisptr != NULL;)
    {
        lap* tempptr = thisptr; 
        thisptr = thisptr.next_ptr;
        free (tempptr); 
    }
    cur_state = FINISHED;
}
```

I have not actually tried to compile anything yet, but I have a few questions before I proceed.

(1) Is my logic for freeing the linked list correct? The procedure I used is

(i) Set thisptr equal to the pointer to the first lap.

(ii) While thisptr isn't NULL, store a copy of thisptr, increment thisptr, then free the memory that the copy points to

which seems correct, but then again pointers are still tricky for me.

(2) Am I supposed to set a pointer equal to `NULL` after using `free` on it? In all the code samples I've seen so far, when the writer wanted to get rid of a variable they simply used `free` on it. But I was reading this guy's instructions http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson6.html and he says to set it equal to `NULL` afterwards. I've always thought his tutorials were good.

(3) Do I need to use a `namespace` operator when I'm referring to `lap*` in my destructor? I.e., do I need to write `Stopwatch::lap*` instead of `lap*` ??? Did I even declare the `lap` structure in the correct place inside my class?

Comment: Is this actually supposed to be C, or is it C++?

Comment: I'm trying to use plain, old C

Comment: C doesn't have any constructors or destructors or anything. Data structures consist of variables or nested types and that's it.

Comment: I would try  while(thisptr != NULL){tempptr = thisptr; thisptr = thisptr.next_ptr; free (tempptr)}  This will free all the nodes of the linked list

Comment: @user3566398 a user changed the tags on you to be C++ instead of C. If you are *really* trying to write C, you need to start over because this code won't compile.

Answer (score 1):

Setting a pointer to NULL after releasing it is not necessary. It can be recommended so that if there is a use after a free() the code will (should...) crash immediately and it is easier to debug.
However in C++ you should NOT need it, because you should RAII and never have raw pointer with ownership.

Note also that in C++ you use `new` and `delete`, not `malloc` and `free`.

You for loop is not very idiomatic, it looks more like a while loop so it is more readable this way:

```
lap* thisptr = first_ptr;
while(thisptr)
{
    lap* tempptr = thisptr; 
    thisptr = thisptr.next_ptr;
    free (tempptr); 
}
```

The logic seem OK. However if it is not some homework project, you should change a few things:

1) Use standard containers. If you can use vector, then use it. If your code does not fit vector, rethink it to use vector ;-)
You don't need a destructor if you change you code this way:

```
class Stopwatch
{
    ...
    typedef struct
    {
       unsigned n; // lap number
       time t; // lap time
    } lap;

    ...

    private: 
    ...
    std::list<lap> laps; // Could you use vector?

}
```

Note, in C++ you usually declare a struct this way:

```
    struct lap
    {
       unsigned n; // lap number
       time t; // lap time
    };
```

And you can refer to it using `lap` inside the Stopwatch class.

2) C++11 provides date/time utility:

```
class Stopwatch
{
    ...
    typedef std::chrono::system_clock::time_point time;
    ...
}
```

3) It is good practice to use initializer list in you constructor:

```
Stopwatch::Stopwatch()
  : cur_state(UNSTARTED)
{
}
```

You don't even need a constructor for simple cases in C++11:

```
class Stopwatch
{
    ...
    private: 
    state cur_state = UNSTARTED;
    ...
}
```

Note also that changing the state to `FINISHED` in the destructor is pretty much useless, as the object is... destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

1) The logic looks good to me. I can't promise it will work without trying it, but the idea is right.

2) If a pointer is visible to other code, it's a good idea to set it to null after `free`ing or `delete`ing it so everyone will understand it's no longer pointing at anything valid. But if you're in a destructor where everything's about to go away anyway, it doesn't really matter that much. If the reset functionality in left_button actually frees the list, though, you'd want to set first_ptr to null at the end of that.

3) No, you don't need to explicitly scope to your own class when you're inside it.